# Route path after `route del`

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have two virtual machine, one is 192.168.1.233, the other is 192.168.1.234.

At first, they all have two routes:
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0`

Then, in 192.168.1.233, I run `route del -net 192.168.1.0/24`,so it has only one default route left.

Now I can `ping 192.168.1.234` from 192.168.1.233, but cannot `ping 192.168.1.233` from 192.168.1.234.

I'm confused. Can anyone explain to me? THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out, at least partially. By deleting the local route, the  ICMP reply packet carries the correct IP address for the reply, but the wrong MAC address. In fact, the MAC address used in this case is that of the  router, not that of the pinging machine.

This behavior (using the MAC address of the router) is correct whenever the pc wants the router to take care of the packet for further routing. For instance, if you try to ping 8.8.8.8 from the pc without the local route, the ICMP packet carries as destination the MAC address of the router, which (alone) will grab it and see what is to be done with it (send it on its way on the WAN side, in this last case).

But the ill-formed ICMP reply is sent to the router, which cannot send it away on its WAN side, and it cannot send it to its intended recipient because the MAC address does **not** correspond to its IP address.

Hence the packet is dropped.

You should leave your local route in place.